# How to Serialize Tree Structure Data From Database to JSON

Tags: c#, json, tree

I have data in a data store which represents a tree structure. Following code represents how it can be described in a simple DataTable in C#.

```
using System.Data;

namespace DemoConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable treeData = new DataTable();
            treeData.Clear();
            treeData.Columns.Add("NodeId", typeof(int));
            treeData.Columns.Add("ParentNodeId", typeof(int));
            treeData.Columns.Add("Data", typeof(string));
            treeData.Columns.Add("AbsolutePath", typeof(string));

            DataRow record1 = treeData.NewRow();
            record1["NodeId"] = 1;
            record1["ParentNodeId"] = 0;
            record1["Data"] = "Dairy";
            record1["AbsolutePath"] = "/Dairy/";
            treeData.Rows.Add(record1);

            DataRow record2 = treeData.NewRow();
            record2["NodeId"] = 2;
            record2["ParentNodeId"] = 1;
            record2["Data"] = "Yoghurt";
            record2["AbsolutePath"] = "/Dairy/Yoghurt";
            treeData.Rows.Add(record2);

            DataRow record3 = treeData.NewRow();
            record3["NodeId"] = 3;
            record3["ParentNodeId"] = 1;
            record3["Data"] = "Cheese";
            record3["AbsolutePath"] = "/Dairy/Cheese";
            treeData.Rows.Add(record3);

            DataRow record4 = treeData.NewRow();
            record4["NodeId"] = 4;
            record4["ParentNodeId"] = 2;
            record4["Data"] = "Flavored";
            record4["AbsolutePath"] = "/Dairy/Yoghurt/Flavored";
            treeData.Rows.Add(record4);
        }
    }
}
```

I need to serialize the data into the following structure.

```
{
  "TreeData": {
    "NodeId" : "1",
    "Data" : "Dairy",
    "Children": [
      {
        "NodeId": "2",
        "Data": "Yohurt",
        "Children": [
          {
              "NodeId": "4",
              "Data": "Flavored",
              "Children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "NodeId": "3",
        "Data": "Cheese",
        "Children": []
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

How do i go about achieving this?

Comment: How have you attempted to achieve the conversion? Have you tried [JSON.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have used JSON.net, my question is, how to iterate through the data and represent it in JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new class:

```
class Node
{
    public int NodeId;
    public int ParentNodeId;
    public string Data;
    public string AbsolutePath;
    public List<Node> Children = new List<Node>();
}
```

Then iterate over rows of the DataTable, create an appropriate tree structure and simply call JsonConvert.SerializeObject()

```
var nodes = new Dictionary<int, Node>();
foreach(DataRow record in treeData.Rows)
{
    var node = new Node { NodeId = (int)record["NodeId"], ParentNodeId = (int)record["ParentNodeId"], Data = (string)record["Data"], AbsolutePath = (string)record["AbsolutePath"] };
    nodes.Add(node.NodeId, node);
}

var rootNodeId = 1;
var rootNode = nodes[rootNodeId];
foreach(var keyValuePair in nodes)
{
    var node = keyValuePair.Value;
    if(node.NodeId != rootNodeId)
    {
        nodes[node.ParentNodeId].Children.Add(node);
    }
}

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootNode, Formatting.Indented);
Debug.WriteLine(json);
```

Output:

```
{
  "NodeId": 1,
  "ParentNodeId": 1,
  "Data": "Dairy",
  "AbsolutePath": "/Dairy/",
  "Children": [
    {
      "NodeId": 2,
      "ParentNodeId": 1,
      "Data": "Yoghurt",
      "AbsolutePath": "/Dairy/Yoghurt",
      "Children": [
        {
          "NodeId": 4,
          "ParentNodeId": 1,
          "Data": "Flavored",
          "AbsolutePath": "/Dairy/Flavored",
          "Children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "NodeId": 3,
      "ParentNodeId": 1,
      "Data": "Cheese",
      "AbsolutePath": "/Dairy/Cheese",
      "Children": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I can't hand code each row in the data store! (what I gave was an example) What I am looking for is the iteration logic. That's the question really.

Comment: I have updated the answer to base on the iteration logic.

Answer (score 0):

My aproach would be to create an object (TreeDataNode, for example) and giving this object the following variables

```
public class TreeDataNode{
    int nodeId;
    string data;
    List<TreeDataNode> children;

    public void AddChildren(string relativePath, TreeDataNode node)
    {
        string[] path = relativePath.Split('/');
        if(path.Count<2)
        {
            children.Add(node);
        }else
        {
            string newPath = String.Join(@"/", relativePath.Split('\\').Skip(1));
            children.First(n=> n.data==path[0]).AddChildren(newPath,node);
        }
    }
}
```

Once you populate this object, having a parent TreeDataNode and the subsequent children, you just have to serialize it with any standard JSON serializer, and you would have a structure just like the one you are trying to achieve.

Now, you just need to be sure to add your objects in order, never a parent after his children, and it will be alright. Create your parent TreeDataNode with the root object, and then call AddChildren for every object on this parent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But it's just representing JSON in C#, what I need to know is an approach to iterate through the data and populating an object of the class you propose.

Comment: Once you have this object, you just need to iterate your DataTable (or where you have your original data) and populate it using an object like "AddChildren(string AbsolutePath)" where you select the correct parent with the absolute path and add a new children

Answer (score 0):

```
you need to make custom recursive function with Serialization Class
which will append Children till you get leaf node.
Below is example for that. please use your logic to append JsonString
var appendJsonString;

Private string PassParentId(int Id)
{
      var childnodecount=0;
      childnodecount=getchildnode(Id);   
     while(childnodecount>0)
     {
       getchilddata=getchildnode(Id);
       childnodecount=getchilddata.count();
       appendJsonString = getchilddata();
    }
    return appendJsonString;
}
```